# jquery assign value on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a url that returns some text. I would assign this string to the region variable. How can I do it?

```
var region="";
$.get("retrieve/region", function(data) {
    region=data;
    alert(data);
});

alert("r= "+region);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function defined inside the `$.get()` call won't run right away, so your `alert` prints the value of `region` before the `$.get()` callback has assigned it a value. If you put the `alert` inside of the function, so that it ran after the value was assigned, you would see that [your code does indeed work (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dghbe/).

Comment: @michele I forgot about that, but be warned that your page will stop responding while it is making the request, so this can be disruptive if your user's connection is slow.